# How can i join table with second table latest record

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

i have two table like registration table and academicdetails table and i have two records in academic table according to registration id but i want to join with latest record of academic table.

Query:

```
SELECT a.*, b.status AS ac_status 
FROM registration AS a 
LEFT JOIN academicdetails AS b ON a.id = b.registration_id 
WHERE b.status = '1' 
ORDER BY id DESC 
LIMIT 100
```

PHP code:

```
if(isset($search['category']) && $search['category']!=''){
         $condition = ', TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, a.dob, CURDATE()) AS age';
    }

    $this->db->select('a.*,b.status as ac_status'.$condition);
    $this->db->from("registration as a");
    $this->db->join('academicdetails as b','a.id = b.registration_id','left');
    if(isset($search['search_by_name']) && $search['search_by_name']!=''){
         $this->db->where('a.name', $search['search_by_name']);
    }
    if(isset($search['gender']) && $search['gender']!=''){
         $this->db->where('a.gender', $search['gender']);
    }

    if(isset($search['status']) && $search['status']!=''){
            $this->db->where('b.status', $search['status']);
    }

    if(isset($search['category']) && $search['category']!=''){
         if($search['category']=='Youth'){
          $this->db->where('age>10 AND age<18');
         }elseif($search['category']=='Junior'){
          $this->db->where('age>17 AND age<22');
         }elseif($search['category']=='Senior'){
          $this->db->where('age > 21');
         }
    }

    if(isset($search['course']) && $search['course']!=''){
         $this->db->where('b.course', $search['course']);
    }

    $this->db->limit($search['limit'], $search['start']);
    $this->db->order_by($this->id, $this->order);
    $this->db->group_by('a.id');
    $query = $this->db->get();
```

Comment: It looks like this is PHP code, but what framework are you using? Is the code relevant, or could you just post MySQL queries? Sorry, but your question is very difficult to understand this way.

Comment: This code in code igniter

Comment: SELECT `a`.*, `b`.`status` as `ac_status`
FROM `registration` as `a`
LEFT JOIN `academicdetails` as `b` ON `a`.`id` = `b`.`registration_id`
WHERE `b`.`status` = '1'
ORDER BY `id` DESC
 LIMIT 100

Comment: I added your query to the question, to help the readers.

Answer (score 0):

Please try following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `registration` LEFT JOIN academicdetails on registration.id = academicdetails.id ORDER BY academicdetails.id desc LIMIT 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
$this->db->select("a.*, b.status AS ac_status");
$this->db->from('registration AS a');
$this->db->join('academicdetails AS b', 'b.registration_id = a.id', 'left');
$this->db->where("b.status",1);
$this->db->order_by("b.id","DESC");//primary key or id of your academic table.
$this->db->limit(100);
$this->db->get();
```